# Shorten dict comprehension with repeated operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

```py
dc = {line.split('=')[0]: line.split('=')[1] for line in txt}
```

Below avoids duplication but is even longer:

```py
dc = {k: v for line in txt for k, v in
      zip(*map(lambda x: [x], line.split('=')))}
```

Any better way? Just without any imports.

---

Context: `with open('config.txt', 'r') as f: txt = f.read().split('\n')`

```py
a=1
bc=sea
```

```
>>> {'a': '1', 'bc': 'sea'}  # desired output; values should be string
```

Comment: Just FYI, Python has a built-in [`ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser) for parsing configration files in INI format, which requires a section header for each section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dc = dict(line.split('=') for line in txt)
```

Comment: I knew Python had to have better - excellent.

Answer (score 3):

```py
{k: v for line in txt for k, v in [line.split('=')]}
```

Advantage over `superb rain`'s answer is ability to modify `k` and `v` if needed. Slight memory & speed advantage by avoiding allocation via a generator (credit @GZ0):

```py
{k: v for k, v in (line.split('=') for line in txt)}
```

Comment: @Graipher That's the idea, `line` is split into a "left' and "right", key and value, so a 'trick' around duplicating `line.split`.

Comment: You could also write `(line.split("="),)` to avoid allocating a list.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq That creates a tuple, which in this case is not much different from a list. One approach to avoid allocating a new collection is this: `{k: v for k, v in (line.split('=') for line in txt)}`

Comment: @GZ0 Nice improvement - can post as answer if you wish, or I'll edit it into mine with credit.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon You can edit it into yours.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the types of problems that the walrus operator `:=` can handle:

```
dc = {(s := line.split('='))[0]: s[1] for line in txt}
```

Of course, in this case there's a much cleaner solution.